# No type or protocol named 'NSTableViewDataSource'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQqOl12lmBE) NSTableView tutorial. I am using Xcode 7.3.1. When it comes time to create the table controller class and make it conform to NSTableViewDataSource (around 5:11 in the video) is when I run into a problem. As I try to type NSTableViewDataSource within the <>, it does not appear in the autocomplete, and if I put NSTableViewDataSource in manually, I get "No type or protocol named 'NSTableViewDataSource'". I can't figure out why this is. The tutorial was created with Xcode 5, and things are different in Xcode 7. I created the class by going to File > New > File. There is no "Objective C Class" option in Xcode 7, so I choose "Cocoa Class" under OS X. I made it a subclass on NSObject like in the video, and called it TableController. I then attempted to make it conform to NSTableViewDataSource, where I ran into the problem. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to create the class in a different way?

Comment: Does the new class header import Cocoa.h?

Comment: No, but it doesn't in the video either. This video is from the article below and there is a github link at the bottom. In the github project, Cocoa.h is not imported into the TableController class.
If I import Cocoa.h, the error does go away. But I don't understand why it works in the video, but it doesn't work for me.
http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-populate-an-nstableview-in-code/

Comment: It's imported in the pch: https://github.com/versluis/Mac-TableViewCode/blob/master/Mac%20TableViewCode/Mac%20TableViewCode-Prefix.pch Make sure you either have one or the other. Somebody else had the same problem as you already: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-populate-an-nstableview-in-code/#comment-55170

Comment: My project doesn't have a pch. I guess Xcode 7 doesn't create one? I'll just import Cocoa.h into the TableController class. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please post an answer with your solution when you resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply importing Cocoa.h into the TableController class solves the problem. The reason it worked in Xcode 5 in the tutorial is because Xcode 5 (and probably older versions as well) created a pch file that imported Cocoa.h into every source file, therefore eliminating the need to import it into the TableController class manually. It seems that starting with Xcode 6, a pch file is no longer created with new projects, which is why you have to manually import Cocoa.h into the class. You import Cocoa.h by simply putting `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` either above or below the Foundation import line in the new class.